# PyQGIS (Spatial Join): Sum features of attribute from point layer and join with vector layer

Tags: qgis, python, spatial-join

I am new to Python and QGIS. I have developed a reasonable idea of where I want to go so and where I am stuck.

I am using QGIS 2.0.1 and Python 2.6.1

What I need: I have a layer consisting of polygons which I want to spatially join with a layer of points. However, I am particularly interested in the sum of features of a particular attribute from the points layer which I want to join with the vector layer to conduct my analysis. Hope that was sufficiently clear.

I am still in the process of understanding what is happening. Thus, would be happy about any advice on how to proceed. What I have understood so far:

```
#_Set the scene_

qgis.utils.iface
import qgis.core

#_Import stuff_

LayerVector=QgsVectorLayer("x.shp", "x_name", "org")
LayerPoint=QgsVectorLayer("y.shp", "y_name", "org")

#_Define stuff_

VectorI=LayerVector.fieldNameIndex('bearing')
PointI=LayerPoint.fieldNameIndex('bearing')
VectorF=LayerVector.getFeatures()
PointF=LayerPoint.getFeatures()

#_edit_

VectorF.startEditing()

#_loop stuff_

for i in VectorF:
    for j in PointF:
       if j().intersects(i.geometry()) == True:
```

Some function creating an attribute and accumulating integers from features fulfilling the above statement.

```
#_edit_

VectorF.commitChanges()
```

Comment: PyQGIS uses Python 2.x and not 3.x